# Will a DDR3 532 MHz CL7 work with DDR3 1333 MHz CL9?

Tags: memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade my laptop's RAM but I doubt wether the combination will work. Are there any risks of damage?

Here are the specifications of my laptop:

- Processor         : Core i3 M380 @ 2.53 GHz
- Ram Installed     : 2 GB DDR3 532.1 MHz, CL7.
- Operating System  : Windows-7 Ultimate (64-bit)

The RAM I want to install: 4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz CL9.

If it works will I get 6 gigabytes of RAM?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Yes, but it's not recommended.

Both must have the same MHz and sometimes both must be from the same brand. You need to keep in mind though that all the modules will operate at the speed of the lowest frequency module; i.e. if you have two modules wherein one operates at 533 MHz and the other at 667 MHz, then, the 667 MHz module will get down-clocked.

It will work but for better performance get the *same exact RAM*, if possible. If you couldn't, the closest you can find:

- same voltage
- same frequency
- same/similar timings (i.e. 9-9-9-24)

Comment: -1 You can't say "Yes....." and then  say "Both must have the same brand" when in the question they don't have the same MHz.  However you then try to explain yourself, you've been inconsistent and contradicted yourself.  You also haven't mentioned the term  "CL". which is worth mentioning since it's in his subject.